# In GTest, how to check for number very close to 0? EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ not working

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest

I have some code that computes (a)sin/(a)cos values which are expected to be very close to 0, but when I say

```
EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ(my_computed_var, 0);
```

I get errors like:

```
/path/to/my/test.cpp:148: Failure
      Expected: my_computed_var
      Which is: 9.9920072e-16
      To be equal to: 0
```

How should I do this?  I get this type of "error" for other numbers as well:  `-4.3711388e-08`

Looking for both specific suggestions and general information about dealing with floating point error like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use [`EXPECT_NEAR`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#floating-point-comparison) or the [`FloatEq`](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#floating-point-matchers-fpmatchers) matcher instead.

[Floating-Point Macros](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#floating-point-comparison) said that `EXPECT_FLOAT_EQ` `EXPECT_DOUBLE_EQ` `ASSERT_FLOAT_EQ` and `ASSERT_DOUBLE_EQ` will verify

> the two `float`/`double` values are almost equal

and:

> By "almost equal", we mean the two values are within 4 ULP's from each other.

with ULP is stand for [Unit in the last places](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_in_the_last_place)

Comment: any idea what types of operations are good to use expect_float_eq for?  or how to know if I'm "doing it wrong"?

Comment: @xaxxon I add some explanation taken from that document

Comment: Thanks, that helps.

Comment: "Floating-Point-Macros" link is dead. Use: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googletest/docs/advanced.md#floating-point-comparison

Comment: Updated links: https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/advanced.md#floating-point-comparison, https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/docs/gmock_cheat_sheet.md#floating-point-matchers-fpmatchers

Comment: It would sure be nice if the error said "if you expect this to not fail, you should use "EXACT_TEST_TO_USE(..., VALUE_TO_USE)" for the test to pass given the current values.  I don't even remember the situation when I asked this, but just looking at it in hindsight it feels crazy that 9e-16 fails this test